# Anyway to increase amount of opened tabs in “Other Devices” list on the new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Google Chrome every day at work and at home. All stuff is synced. So usually I can view at work, that what I was viewing at home with help of “Other Devices” popup menu.

But yesterday I opened a large amount of tabs and at work I can see only a few of all opened tabs. What might be the reason? Is there some limit and if so, then can it be changed? Or it should display all and it might be due to not enough time to sync after I opened them? Because I opened them quite fast and closed browser.